# How can I find particular value from array in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find each link value  in different variables according to their name , like if name if facebook then facebooklink should filter , same lite twitter and all . But don't want to give index number . sometime fabook should be o index sometime twitter will be on 0 index . Please help

```
socialMediaDetails:
            socialMediaDetail: Array(2)
            0:
            link: "HARIRAM@twitter.com"
            name: "twitter"
            __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
            __proto__: Object
            1:
            link: "VarnaHERO@facebook.com"
            name: "facebook"
            __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
            __proto__: Object
            2:
            link: "linkedIn@linkedin.com"
            name: "linkedIn"
            __typename: "SocialMediaDetail"

        const socialMediaData=socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail;

            const Steplabels = socialMediaData.filter((item) => {
              return item.name === "twitter"
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: So, what is the issue with the code you've posted? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: by above code this code is coming while i want only name  
                link: "HARIRAM@twitter.com"
                 name: "twitter"
            __typename: "SocialMediaDetail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find` method, like this:

```
requiredMediaByName = (name) => {
 return state.socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail.find(data => data.name === name);
}; 
console.log(requiredMediaByName('facebook'));
```

Note that `find` returns the first matching element in the array and it won't check the other elements if you get it on fist match. If you want all the elements to be returned then you should use for loop and get all of them.

Comment: @Abhigyan Gaurav `find` is best if you wanna get the first matched values than using for loops and filter

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways this can be achieved - the simplest way would be to use a `for .. of` loop if you're just looking for the first item matching on `name`:

```
function findLinkByName(name) {
  for (const item of state.socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail) {
    if (item.name === name) {
      return item.link;
    }
  }
}
```

For other cases such as returning a subset of items where multiple matches on `name` exist, then a simple solution based on `filter()` and `map()` could be achieved like this:

```
function findLinksByName(name) {
  return state.socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail
    .filter(item => item.name === name)
    .map(item => item.link);
}
```

Here's a snippet showing both in action:

```js
var state = {
  socialMediaDetails: {
    socialMediaDetail: [{
        link: "HARIRAM@twitter.com",
        name: "twitter"
      }, {
        link: "VarnaHERO@facebook.com",
        name: "facebook"
      }, {
        link: "linkedIn@linkedin.com",
        name: "linkedIn"
      }, {
        link: "another twitter link",
        name: "twitter"
      }
    ]
  }
}

/* 
Find link of first item matching by name (or undefined if no match found) 
*/
function findLinkByName(name) {
  for (const item of state.socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail) {
    if (item.name === name) {
      return item.link;
    }
  }
}

/* 
Find links for all items with matching name (or empty array if no
matches found) 
*/
function findLinksByName(name) {
  return state.socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail
    .filter(item => item.name === name)
    .map(item => item.link);
}

console.log(findLinkByName('twitter'));
console.log(findLinkByName('facebook'));
console.log(findLinksByName('twitter'));
console.log(findLinksByName('facebook'));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks I tried this ..is this correct 
 const twitterDatavalue = socialMediaData.filter((item) => {

    return item.name === "twitter"

  });
  console.log("Link data",twitterDatavalue[0].link);

Comment: You're welcome - not quite seeing `filter()` will return an array. You could do this: 
`const twitterDatavalue = socialMediaData.filter((item) => item.name === "twitter")[0];`

Comment: @AbhigyanGaurav please consider marking this answer as accepted by clicking the "grey tick" next to the answer if it has been helpful !

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

1. if you only want to know if the value exists or not

   var doesExist = arr.some(function(ele) {
   return ele.id === '21';
   });
2. If you want to get the value you are searching for:

   var data = arr.find(function(ele) {
   return ele.id === '21';
   });

   if (data) {
   console.log('found');
   console.log(data); // This is entire object i.e. `item` not boolean
   }

I have used following array for this example:

```
var arr = [];
var item1 = {
    id: 21,
    label: 'Banana',
};
var item2 = {
    id: 22,
    label: 'Apple',
};
arr.push(item1, item2);
```